# Render results in template on completed request from server

Tags: javascript, angular

I am building my first Angular app and need some help. The component I'm working on is an image search box. The user enters search query, request is sent to API, API responds with JSON data. Why is my *ngFor loop not working? The iterable is updated when the server sends response.

image-search.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ImageSearchService } from './image-search.service';
import { Image } from '../shared/image';

@Component({
  selector: 'vb-image-search',
  templateUrl: './image-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./image-search.component.css'],
  providers: [ImageSearchService]
})
export class ImageSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  images: Image[] = [];
  constructor(private ImageSearchService: ImageSearchService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getImages(query: string) {
    this.ImageSearchService.getImages(query)
                            .subscribe(function(images) {
                              this.images = images;
                            });
  }

  onClick(query:string) {
    this.getImages(query);
  }

}
```

image-search.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { Image } from '../shared/image';


@Injectable()
export class ImageSearchService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getImages(query: string): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/search/${query}`)
                    .map(this.extractData)
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data.map(e => new Image(e.farmID, e.serverID, e.imageID, e.secret)) || {};
  }
}
```

image.ts

```
export class Image {
  constructor(public farmID: string, public serverID: string, public imageID: string, public secret: string) {
    this.farmID = farmID;
    this.serverID = serverID;
    this.imageID = imageID;
    this.secret = secret;
  }
}
```

image-search.component.html

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="query" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for images..." />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button (click)="onClick(query)" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <h2>Images</h2>
  <div *ngFor="let image of images">
    {{image.imageID}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see you have defined `getImages` to be called `onClick`. Have you verified that is working? Is `images` being filled up? Are there any console errors?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is very simple. In typescript the function call back loses the current scope if you use function(){} so instead you have to used  => {} to retain the current scope. So please modify your current getImages method as mentioned below:

```
 getImages(query: string) {
      this.ImageSearchService.getImages(query)
                        .subscribe(images => {
                          this.images = images;
                        });
 }
```